# Accidentally deleted torrent on uTorrent

Tags: windows, data-recovery, bittorrent, utorrent, recycle-bin

So I've been downloading this torrent for 3 days now, its 180GB and instead of pause I somehow clicked delete torrent+data. The data and torrent is in the recycle bin still. How do I get them back to utorrent so it continues downloading? Is there maybe a way to access Recycle Bin without double-clicking it? I cant go to the Recycle Bin and just clicked Restore All Files because its just loading infinitely.

Comment: Restore the data, then import the torrent, back into uTorrent.

Comment: Be patient. Your computer may be slow or you may have lots of files in the Recycle Bin. Wait for it to finish loading and restore the missing files.

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah I had the same idea, but my Recycle Bin kept crashing, so I must manually choose about a 3000-4000 files and restore them, but I think it will to the job, thanks

Comment: Out of 130GB I had downloaded I only recovered 68GB, Recuva scan didnt find anything to recover too

Comment: Recovery software wouldn’t because the files were never deleted unless you also emptied the recycle bin.

Answer (score 1):

Torrenting is an excellent way of recovering data in an inconsistent state.  Move the folder back to the default download folder.  Get the .torrent file again and open it in the app you use.  It will verify the files that are successfully downloaded and continue downloading the rest.  You might have trouble with the partially downloaded files - mine are set to a temp extension so that it's easy to tell them apart from finished files.