# How to know if a torrent has been downloaded

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, bittorrent, utorrent

I know the title sounds stupid but just, read the question. So I asked [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1294719/accidentally-deleted-torrent-on-utorrent) question couple of days ago. Unfortunately I managed to restore only 68GB and those same 68GB I permanently deleted. So, I started downloading the same torrent, but on a different location this time. Now uTorrent is showing that I downloaded 78.1GB(46%) - full size is 172GB(168GB without some extras), and when I go to the location and click on properties it says that the size of the folder is indeed 168GB and I downloaded 168GB(see [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvQzB.jpg) ). My question is - Should I wait for uTorrent to say its 100% finished, or should I trust "Windows" and install it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know uTorrent specifically, but many file downloaders reserve space on the drive before they start - so the file shows with its final size right from the beginning.
This, of course serves two purposes, first that the drive has sufficient space before the task even begins & secondly that it will *continue* to have sufficient space right until the end.

Trust the downloader to know when it's finished, not Windows.